# How do you sort an alpha-numeric list in excel?

Tags: excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm  trying to sort a list of documents, but I'm having an issue with the documents that have a letter as a suffix.

Whenever we amend a document we add a letter to the end of the number, but when I sort by number in excel it sorts like this:

```
1
2
3
10
11
1606
1603D
1605B
1606A
1606C
1610A
1623A
20A
220B
390A
399A
402A
415A
450A
488A
557B
```

How can I make it sort in order of document number and amendment?
Like so:

```
1
2
3
10
11
1603D
1605B
1606
1606A
1606C
1610A
1623A
20A
220B
390A
399A
402A
415A
450A
488A
557B
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a mix of text and number, you won't be able to use Excel's built-in sort to achieve the result you describe.

If you append a letter to a number you effectively change the data type from number to text. Text will always be sorted **after** any number, hence the number 1606 comes before the text 1606A.

You could try to make all values real text, maybe indicate levels by appending digits with dots, like this:

```
1.
1.0.
1.1.
1.6.0.3.D
1.6.0.5.B
1.6.0.6.
1.6.0.6.A
1.6.0.6.C
1.6.1.0.A
1.6.2.3.A
2.
2.0.A.
2.2.0.B.
3.
3.9.0.A.
3.9.9.A.
4.0.2.A.
4.1.5.A.
4.5.0.A.
4.8.8.A.
5.5.7.B.
```

But even that does not give you the sort order you describe as the desired result.

Your desired sort order will be hard to achieve even if all values are text, or if you replace the A, B, C with a decimal .1, .2, .3. -- It's really hard to understand why 20 would come after 1623.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to add a column, and copy this formula into each cell:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(A2)),A2,LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1))
```

The formula removes the letters from the numbers, you can then sort your sheet using the new column of clean numbers.